# Avoiding React Synthetic Event warnings when onBlur is triggered upon object disappearance

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am making a "wizard" style form, and I also have onBlur handlers to track with items have been touched already.

Unfortunately, when the user hits "enter" to go to the next page. It triggers a slew of "Synthetic Event" warnings. Likely, it's because the field no longer exists by the time the action runs, which contains this line to capture the form element:

```
const name = event.target.name;
```

My setup is like this:

```
<ShowIf show={this.props.page === 1}>
  <input ... />
  <button onBlur={this.props.actions.onBlur} onClick={this.props.actions.onClick} ... />
</Show>
```

Where ShowIf is an element that renders the children only if the condition is valid.

The event is not triggered if I click out of the field first. I haven't found any very elegant workaround yet. I tried putting an onTimeout on the nextPage action, but the onBlur would just wait until the page change was triggered defeating the purpose.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Can you copy and paste an example of the exact warning you're seeing? Also the code from your actions.onBlur action creator please. I know what the problem is but I need to see your action creator code to give you a solid explanation for why it's happening. I've had to solve this in my own code base many times.